# Twitter Streaming API (filter method) - limitations

Tags: api, twitter, filter, streaming, limit

I am using the streaming API - filter method with the location parameter and with coordinates set for New York (-74,40,-73,41).
I get the data but the issue is that there are no much tweets coming in (like 1 or 2 tweets per second). I get more (unique) data using the search methods in a loop for the same location parameter.

What could be the cause of these limitations and is there any way to get more tweets from the streaming?

Thanks and best regards,
Leo

Answer (score 3):

### **What could be the cause of these limitations?**

Twitter Streaming API doesn't deliver any past tweets. You only receive tweets starting from the time the server connection is established. The search API will return tweets matching the current query up to 7 days old in theory, but that is entirely up to Twitter’s current load. (Note*-At times this interval has been as short as 24 hours. In addition, you are limited by the ability to only receive up to 1,500 tweets regardless of how old they are.)

### **Is there any way to get more tweets from the streaming?**

None that I know. But, do refer the below mentioned information if you are considering to switch among search or streaming API.

Please choose your case:

- If you need real time data and your number of requests are high:

**Go for Streaming API**

The streaming API requires that you keep the connection active. This requires a server process with an infinite loop, to get the latest tweets.

Advantage

1)Lag in retrieving results: Tweets delivered with this method are basically real-time, with a lag of a second or two at most between the time the tweet is posted and it is received from the API

2)Not rate limited.

- If you need aggregate data regardless of its time range and your number of requests are not high:

**Go for Search API**

The search API is the easier of the two methods to implement but it is rate limited .Each request will return up to 100 tweets, and you can use a page parameter to request up to 15 pages, giving you a theoretical maximum of 1,500 tweets for a single query.

Advantage

1)Finding tweets in the past:The search API wins by default in this area, because the streaming API doesn’t deliver any past tweets

2)Easier to implement

Comment: Thanks Samridhi for clarifications!